# Why does Vue evaluate my v-if to false despite it being true?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

When I run this, vue returns the second template, even though `groups.length is equal` to 1.
Why? Does it have to do with the order in which the mounting occurs and v-if is evaluated? Again, I am certain that `groups.length` evaluates to 1. I have tried using `beforeMount` as opposed to `mounted`, but that did not work.

```
<template v-if = "groups.length">
    <ul id = "groupList">
        <li v-for = "group in groups">
            <a>{{ group.name }}</a>
        </li>
        <div class = "addSidebar">
            <label class = "btn" for = "modal-1">+</label>
        </div>
    </ul>
</template>
<template v-else>
    <ul id = "groupList">
        <li>
            <a>You have not created/joined any groups.</a>
        </li>
        <div class = "addSidebar">
            <label class = "btn" for = "modal-1">+</label>
        </div>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            groups: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getGroups() {
            axios.get('groupList').then((response) => {
                this.groups = response.data
            }).catch((errors) => {
                console.log(errors)
            });
        },
        newModal() {
            $('#modal').modal('show');
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getGroups()
    },
    name: "groupList"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Firstafall if groups is an array then it should be initialized with [] and not {}

Comment: Also make sure that the response.data is an array and not object becoz .length will apply only for arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use javascript Async

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp

```
<template >
    <div>
        <ul id="groupList" v-if="groups.length">
            <li v-for="group in groups" :key="group.id">
                <a>{{ group.name }}</a>
            </li>
            <div class="addSidebar">
                <label class="btn" for="modal-1">+</label>
            </div>
        </ul>

        <ul id="groupList" v-else>
            <li>
                <a>You have not created/joined any groups.</a>
            </li>
            <div class="addSidebar">
                <label class="btn" for="modal-1">+</label>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            groups: {},
        };
    },
    methods: {
        async getGroups() {
            await axios
                .get("groupList")
                .then((response) => {
                    this.groups = response.data;
                })
                .catch((errors) => {
                    console.log(errors);
                });
        },
        newModal() {
            $("#modal").modal("show");
        },
    },
    async mounted() {
        await this.getGroups();
    },
    name: "groupList",
};
</script>
```

in your code you created 2 `<template >` which is not valid syntax and vue should have root element

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
v-if = "groups.length"
```

to:

```
v-if="groups && groups.length > 0"
```

And you should have a single  that contains one elements in it.